# Python More efficient way of finding occurrences in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have this block of code which does work well, but is there a way to make this more efficient and shorter? Can I check all the lists at once and print total occurrences?

my lists are SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP

```
def count_awards():
    awards=0
    for i in SAG:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    for i in oscars:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    for i in NBR:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    for i in ISA:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    for i in GLAAD:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    for i in NAACP:
      if (Movie_title.lower().strip() == i.lower()):
          awards = awards+1
    print(awards)
```

looking to find how many times Movie_title exists in the lists (all of them)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more efficient and concise by using a dictionary to store the awards data, instead of using multiple separate lists. Here's a more efficient way to count the occurrences of Movie_title in multiple award lists:

```
def count_awards():
    award_lists = {
        "SAG": SAG,
        "oscars": oscars,
        "NBR": NBR,
        "ISA": ISA,
        "GLAAD": GLAAD,
        "NAACP": NAACP
    }

    movie_title_lower = Movie_title.lower().strip()
    awards = sum(1 for award_list in award_lists.values() if movie_title_lower in map(str.lower, award_list))

    print(awards)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, but the lists are imported from another file and have their own values there that I am checking for. Would this still work?

Comment: @nhiteking You might need to manually add them to the award_lists, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the lists and use Counter on the combined awards. If you put the counter creation in separate function, you can further calculate the results for multiple movies:

```
from collections import Counter

Movie_title = "A"
SAG = ["a", "b", "c"]
oscars = ["a", "d", "E"]
NBR = ["b", "E", "f", "t"]
ISA = ["b", "e"]
GLAAD = ["A", "C", "e"]
NAACP = ["d", "f"]

def collect_all_awards():
    all_awards = []
    all_awards.extend(SAG)
    all_awards.extend(oscars)
    all_awards.extend(NBR)
    all_awards.extend(ISA)
    all_awards.extend(GLAAD)
    all_awards.extend(NAACP)
    return Counter(map(str.lower, all_awards))

all_awards = collect_all_awards()
print(all_awards[Movie_title.lower().strip()])
# Output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.chain to go through multiple lists in a single for-loop.  Also, you should compute `Movie_title.lower().strip()` only once outside of the loop and place the result in a variable.  the whole process could be implement in a sum() with a comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

...

title   = Movie_title.lower().strip()
awarded = chain(SAG,oscars,NBR, ISA,GLAAD,NAACP)
awards  = sum(a.lower() == title for a in awarded)
```

If you're going to count awards for many different titles, it may be more efficient to build a counter of awards beforehand and use it directly with the title as subscript:

```
# preparation

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

awarded = Counter(map(str.lower,chain((SAG,oscars,NBR, ISA,GLAAD,NAACP))))


...

# usage 

awards = awarded[Movie_title.lower().strip()]
```

A more basic method (without libraries) would be to use a nested loop:

```
title  = Movie_title.lower().strip()
awards = 0
for org in (SAG,oscars,NBR, ISA,GLAAD,NAACP):
    for winner in org:
        awards += winner.lower() == title
```

Or, you could combine the lists  into one and use the count() method:

```
*awarded, = map(str.lower,SAG + oscars + NBR + ISA + GLAAD + NAACP)
awards    = awarded.count(Movie_title.lower().strip())
```